# How can I prevent CakePHP HTML Helper from converting special characters to HTML entities?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to get this result

```
<a href="/categories/view/id"><button>Title here<span> (2) </span></button></a>
```

My problem is when i use

```
<?= $this->Html->link('<button>'.h($category->title).'<span> ('.$cats[$key]['ArticleCount'].')</span></button>', ['action' => 'view', $category->id]) ?>
```

I get `&lt` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `escapeTitle => false` to your `Html->link()` options array, as described in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link).

Comment: Great! I've edited the question to improve searchability.